# ActiveRecord returning first record when data attribute empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, active-model-serializers

I have a method in my controller that finds relationships for a model being passed in as json. It works fine when all the expected attributes are present. But if I exclude one, 'project', my project method giving me the first record instead of nil or Project.none .

#### So when

ActiveModelSerializers::Deserialization.jsonapi_parse(relationship_params['project'] evaluates to {} . Calling project return the equivalent of Project.first

#### project method

```
def project
  Project.find_by(ActiveModelSerializers::Deserialization.jsonapi_parse(relationship_params['project'], only: [:id]))
end
```

#### relationship param

```
def relationship_params
  return false unless params.dig(:data, :relationships)
      params.require(:data).require(:relationships).transform_keys(&:dasherize)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can verify your params hash. But it is normal, that Model.find_by({}) or  Model.find_by(nil) returns fist record;

```
   def project
      find_params =ActiveModelSerializers::Deserialization.jsonapi_parse(relationship_params['project'], only: [:id])
      if find_params.present?
        Project.find_by(find_params)
      else
        nil
      end
    end
```